# Want to increase node export to csv speed in Drupal

Tags: drupal-7

I am working on a site which have a huge database.Currently When i Search the it search will lead to 8000 records displayed. Now when I clieck on export to put these records in Csv file then it take almost 3 minutes to do that.So please let me know how to reduce this time to 1 minute, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Using the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module, [Views data export](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_data_export) you should be able to export CSVs relatively quickly. Otherwise, try writing a MySQL query in [phpMyAdmin](https://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or [Sequel Pro](http://www.sequelpro.com/) and using their export feature.